# Nesting IF AND OR formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have three columns that can be filled with "F", "P", "S" or "". If any column has "F" or "", I need a formula in a fourth column to say "Fail"; any combination of "S" and "P" needs to come back as "Pass".
I have tried many approaches and cannot crack it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g. this formula:
`=IF(COUNTIF(A2:C2,"F")+COUNTIF(A2:C2,""),"Fail","Pass")`

[image]

`COUNTIF`s look for "F" and "", if any of them is found, it returns "Fail", otherwise "Pass"

Answer (score 1):

To do it with `IF` and `OR` (and not `COUNTxxx`), try

```
=IF(OR(A2="F",A2="",B2="F",B2="",C2="F",C2=""), "Fail", "Pass")
```